# Add a new physical volume to Encrypted LVM Group?

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, lvm

I just installed Kubuntu 17.10.1 and chose the LVM encrypted whole disk option, installing on an SSD (/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p5_crypt). I have added a new physical drive with three RAID partitions. I want to add one of these to the encrypted volume and mount it at /home. Can I do this? I would really like 1) to have a single password open the whole thing, and 2) to make sure the /home directory is on the RAID partition, not the SSD.

I guess I'm wondering whether to make a new volume group, encrypt it separately, and mount it at /home, or to add it to the existing root volume group.